# Where can I find Chovoth haLevavoth in Arabic?

Tags: jewish-books, hovot-halevavot

Where can I find Chovoth haLevavoth in Arabic?

Comment: 'original arabic lettering' - the book was always in Hebrew lettering, not Arabic, The language was Arabic but written in Hebrew letters. (A S Yahuda went against tradition and used Arabic script for his modern edition.)

Comment: How did the letters correspond?

Comment: http://www.omniglot.com/writing/judeo-arabic.htm

Comment: @paquda i've run across that picture before. Do you happen to read Arabic? i'm looking for a few specific verses from the book to have made into an art piece, and would really appreciate some help looking for them

Comment: If you just want a short line, I could type it out for you. let me know which, gate, chapter, and the sentence in English or Hebrew.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hovos HaLevavos / Kitab ul-Hidayah ila Fara'idh il-Qulub, as edited by the scholoar A S Yahuda, is available here:

https://archive.org/details/alhidjailfarida00yahugoog

A S Yahuda's edition is in Arabic script. Before that edition, the book was usually (or, I think, always) copied and read in Hebrew script. You can buy an edition in that format, as edited by Rabbi Kafih, and including a translation by Rabbi Kafih into Hebrew:

http://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=5677

Answer (score 1):

Nezah Yisra'el of Qiryat Ono, Israel sells the [R' Yoseph Qafih (parallel Hebrew-Arabic) edition](http://net-sah.org/product/10795) of Hovot HaLevavot.

I recently heard in a sh'iur that the Qafih translation from the original Arabic is far more accurate than that of R' Yehudah Tibbon (the presently more common translation). I have the Feldheim, "Lev Tov", and Qafih editions at home and often cross-reference the Qafih edition as it includes excellent footnotes where R' Qafih disagrees with R' Tibbon's translation.